# Expected value calculation in a white black ball game

Tags: probability

Suppose there are $2N$ balls in a bucket. They are labelled with the numbers $\{1, 2, \dots , 2N\}$. The first $N$ balls are white balls and the others are black balls. We are going to choose $N$ balls from the bucket and put them into a bag. The score of the bag is given by the number of white balls in it, i.e., for each white ball, we get a score of $1$ and for each black ball, we get a score of $0$.

We have automatic selectors to help us do the task. Each selector is associated with a fixed value $p$, $(0.5 < p<1.0)$ and works as follows:

Step 1: Generate a number $r$ using a uniform random number generator on $[0, 1]$.

Step 2: If $r < p$, pick a white ball randomly from the bucket without replacement. Otherwise, pick a black ball randomly.

Step 3: Repeat Step 1 and Step 2 $N$ times.

Here are two strategies to fill the bag:

Strategy 1: Use one selector to choose $N$ balls and put them into the bag.

Strategy 2: Use three independent selectors and record their choices. Combine the choices and make a final decision. The strategy is illustrated in the following Venn diagram.
[image]

In the diagram, the circles represent the sets of balls chosen by the selectors. They have been divided into seven disjoint regions, $R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$, $R_{12}$, $R_{23}$, $R_{31}$ and $R_{123}$. $R_1$ denotes the set of balls exclusively chosen by selector 1. $R_{12}$ denotes the set of balls chosen by both selector 1 and selector 2. $R_{123}$ denotes the set of balls chosen by all the three selectors. $R_2$, $R_3$, $R_{23}$, and $R_{31}$ can be interpreted in a similar way. We use $|R_x|$ to denote the size of the set $R_x$. The procedure of filling the bag is described as follows:

Step 1: Put the balls in set $R_{123}$ into the bag. If $|R_{123}|=N$, end the procedure.

Step 2: If $|R_{12}|+|R_{23}|+|R_{31}|\le N-|R_{123}|$, put all the balls in the set $R_{12} \cup R_{23} \cup R_{31}$ into the bag. Otherwise, randomly choose $N-|R_{123}|$ from the set $R_{12} \cup R_{23} \cup R_{31}$ and end the procedure.

Step 3: If $|R_{123}|+|R_{12}|+|R_{23}|+|R_{31}|=N$, end the procedure. Otherwise, choose $N-|R_{123}|-|R_{12}|-|R_{23}|-|R_{31}|$ balls randomly from the set $R_1 \cup R_2 \cup R_3$ and put them into the bag.

The idea of the second strategy is to first consider the balls in $R_{123}$, and then those in $R_{12} \cup R_{23} \cup R_{31}$ and $R_1 \cup R_2 \cup R_3$. It is not hard to see that with the first strategy, the expected score of the bag is $pN$. What bothers me are the following questions:

What’s the expected score of the bag if we use the second strategy? Can we prove that the expected score with the second strategy is strictly larger than that with the first strategy (i.e., $pN$)?

A very simple example is that $N=1$.
The expected score with the first strategy is $p$.
The expected score with the second strategy is: $p^3+3p^2(1-p) = 3p^2-2p^3$, illustrated in the following figure.
 [image]

We have $p < 3p^2-2p^3$ when $0.5 < p < 1$.

I think the problem has some practical meanings. Suppose there are several wise persons (selectors) who are able to distinguish “good things (white balls)” from “bad things (black balls)” with probability $p > 0.5$. The persons are suggested to make their own choices separately. Then, by combing the choices, we can make better decisions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand so forgive me. What was your question? Find the expected value?

Comment: Sorry for that I didn't describe the question clearly. I want to know the expected value if we use the second strategy to fill the bag. Or can we prove that the expected value is larger than $pN$?